# How to make sql query to show every row while filtering elements?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am filtering my Establishment table by "`category_id`" using sequelize as an ORM. My **problem** is that I am filtering by `category_id = 11` witch produces something like :

Query made:

```
WHERE  `subcategories`.`category_id` = 11;
```

JSON given (only with one subcategory row)

```
"establishments": [
        {
            "id": 11,
            "name": "Tasco do Ti efe",
            "subcategories": [
                {
                    "category_id": 11,
                    "category_type": "fashion",
                    "SubCategoryEstablishements": {
                        "sub_category_id": 31,
                        "establishment_id": 11,
                        "createdAt": "2020-04-26 13:39:20",
                        "updatedAt": "2020-04-26 13:39:20"
                    }
                }
            ],
]
```

I want to be able to find the proper restaurant and have all the subcategories that belong to him like this :

```
"establishments": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Melhor efef",
            "subcategories": [
                {
                "category_id": 21,
                "category_type": "beautycara",
                "SubCategoryEstablishements": {
                    "sub_category_id": 41,
                    "establishment_id": 11,
                    "createdAt": "2020-04-26 13:39:20",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-04-26 13:39:20"
                }
            },
            {
                "category_id": 11,
                "category_type": "fashion",
                "SubCategoryEstablishements": {
                    "sub_category_id": 31,
                    "establishment_id": 11,
                    "createdAt": "2020-04-26 13:39:20",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-04-26 13:39:20"
                }
            },
            {
                "category_id": 31,
                "category_type": "homefamily",
                "SubCategoryEstablishements": {
                    "sub_category_id": 51,
                    "establishment_id": 11,
                    "createdAt": "2020-04-26 13:39:20",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-04-26 13:39:20"
                }
            }
            ],
```

What should I change to my query to make this happen?

Comment: What do you mean by "the proper restaurant?" If you want the restaurant where `category_id = 11`, you're getting exactly what you asked for. Your second example shows records where `category_id` is 21, 11, and 51. Which is it?

Comment: Please mention the relation between establishment and subcategories. Please share the establishment schema for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define two different associations of table `establishment` and `subcategory`. One association will be used for filtering and the other will be used to join `establishment` and `subcategory`.

Your associations should be as follows -

```
subcategory.belongsTo(models.establishment, { foreignKey: 'categoryId', as: 'establishment1' });

subcategory.belongsTo(models.establishment, { foreignKey: 'categoryId', as: 'establishment2' });
```

Your Sequuelize statement should be as follows -

```
const allEstablishments = establishment.findAll({

    include: [{
            model: establishment,
            as: 'establishment1',
            attributes: [],
            required: true,
            where: {
                [op.and]: [{
                    '$`subcategories`.`category_id`$ = 11'
                }]
            }
        },
        {
            model: establishment,
            as: 'establishment2',
            required: true,
        }
    ]

});
```

Hope it helps!